# How to use subquery into where clause?

Tags: java, hibernate, subquery, criteria

We would like to integrate in a query a calculated field.
This calculated field is obtained with a simple `SELECT MAX(x) FROM table2`.

But in our main query, if we want to filter on this calculated field, we had to integrate it in the where clause.

Our problem is to integrate the subquery into a `WHERE...IN` condition.

We try with the `Subqueries.in` function but the problem is we cant inject a list of value.

Here the SQL request we would have.

```
select
    this_.DMDE_CEE_ID as y0_,
    this_.DT_DMDE as y1_,
    (select
        max(this0__.STATUT) as y0_ 
    from
        CS_FC_DMDE_CEE this0__ 
    where
        this0__.DMDE_CEE_ID=this_.DMDE_CEE_ID limit 1 ) as y16_ 
from
    xxx this_ 
where 
    ( select
        max(controleDemandeCee_.STATUT) as y0_ 
        from
            CS_FC_DMDE_CEE controleDemandeCee_ 
        where
            controleDemandeCee_.DMDE_CEE_ID=this_.DMDE_CEE_ID
    ) IN (3,5) 
order by
    this_.NOM_DOS asc,
    this_.DT_DMDE asc limit 10;
```

Here the best result we can have :

```
select
    this_.DMDE_CEE_ID as y0_,
    this_.DT_DMDE as y1_,
    (select
        max(this0__.STATUT) as y0_ 
    from
        CS_FC_DMDE_CEE this0__ 
    where
        this0__.DMDE_CEE_ID=this_.DMDE_CEE_ID limit 1 ) as y16_ 
from
    xxx this_ 
where 
    5 IN ( select
        max(controleDemandeCee_.STATUT) as y0_ 
        from
            CS_FC_DMDE_CEE controleDemandeCee_ 
        where
            controleDemandeCee_.DMDE_CEE_ID=this_.DMDE_CEE_ID
    ) 
order by
    this_.NOM_DOS asc,
    this_.DT_DMDE asc limit 10;
```

The Java code with Criteria & Subqueries :

```
final DetachedCriteria dControleDemande = DetachedCriteria.forClass(ControleDemandeBean.class, CONTROLE);        
dControleDemande.add(Restrictions.eqProperty(CONTROLE_DEMANDE_ID, DMD_ID));
dControleDemande.setProjection(Projections.max(CONTROLE + ".statut.id"));

cDmd.add(Subqueries.in(5L, dControleDemandeCee))
```

We can't replace 5L by a List/Array of Long.

Any idea ?
Thanks

nb: we have to use Criteria. Client refuse native HQL or SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a custom `Criterion` that renders something like

```
( select
        max(controleDemandeCee_.STATUT) as y0_ 
        from
            CS_FC_DMDE_CEE controleDemandeCee_ 
        where
            controleDemandeCee_.DMDE_CEE_ID=this_.DMDE_CEE_ID
) IN (5)
```